# Como fazer o IDE embarcado do Apps Script sugerir uma lista de chaves de um objeto com seu intellisense?

Tags: script

sou novato nessa tecnologia e na própria programação em sí, gostaria muito de uma ajuda nesta questão. Não consigo fazer com que o IDE embarcado na planilha do google me sugira uma lista das chaves de um objeto a medida que coloco um ponto a frente do nome deste objeto.

A intenção é criar um objeto ou função Apps Script que sugira uma lista com os nomes das páginas de uma planilha do google e que apartir da seleção de um dos nomes, retorne o respectivo ID. Este retorno já está efetivo, mas a lista com as chaves do objeto ou seja, os nomes das páginas não aparece como sugestão.
Abaixo segue o código que defini e carrega o objeto com suas propriedades:

```
var pagesGetId = {};
globalThis.pagesGetId = pagesGetId;
function fCarregar() {
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    sheets.forEach((sheet) => {
      Object.defineProperty(this.pagesGetId, sheet.getSheetName(), {
        value: sheet.getSheetId(),
        writable: false,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
      });
    });
};        
fCarregar();
```